# if/else vs virtual function : design performance

Tags: c++, if-statement, virtual-functions

I'm confronted with two designs for getting the root of elements in a hierarchy, which is itself of a derived class.
Just as a matter of curiosity, I was wondering if the most elegant was also the most efficient.
Here is the less elegant version :

```
class Element
{
public:
    Root* root()
    {
        if(mParent)
            return mParent->root();
        else
            return static_cast<Root*>(this);
    }
protected:
    Element* mParent;
};

class Root : public Element
{};
```

And here the more elegant, which instead of an if else uses virtual function to get the root.

```
class Element
{
public:
    virtual Root* root() { return mParent->root(); }
protected:
    Element* mParent;
};

class Root : public Element
{
public:
    virtual Root* root() { return this; }
};
```

I know I shouldn't worry about performance prematurely, and I already chose the second option, but I'm curious on a theoretical level, to know if there are any factors (cache misses ?) that would make one approach superior to another in a context where the function is called very often by the elements ?

Note : I don't believe this question is so "broad" if I add the information that the hierarchy will be in the order of 5-20 elements deep. It's actually quite practical question.

Comment: You should measure your program execution by both way.

Comment: @NOvember Allow me to be the first to say: _yikes_. Can you help me understand the situation in which it would be a good idea to treat a parent class like a child class? I mean if you're only going to call parent functionality on it why not treat both as parent classes?

Comment: Voted for closing as "too broad". I believe one can write a PhD thesis on this.

Comment: @JonathanMee The situation in which the root of a hierarchy of identical elements has more information and features but apart from that behaves exactly like the others. The parent class is never treated like a child class, as the implementer of this code know that the root element is ensured to be of the child Root type. It is just the most straightforward way to retrieve the root from a leaf.

Comment: @JonathanMee: There are plenty of examples of inherited behavior where the behaviors are identical.  For example, in CSS, styles are inherited... but there can be a more specific style definition that provides everything, so that in practice none falls through to the parent.  The only way the general style differs from the specific styles is that the parent is required to provide all styling, because there is no outer style to defer to.  Now, CSS is not a pure tree... but it does show the feasibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Just as a matter of curiosity, I was wondering if the most elegant was
>   also the most efficient.

Atypical. Searching for a good design takes time and experience; optimizing it even more and it's easy to fail. There's really a lot to say but I'll try to narrow it down:

- Need performance? Use the CRTP. I've also seen `switch` statements but that should be your extrema ratio.
- A good design? Use virtual functions. They are very common (e.g. `std::streambuf` uses them) and lots of languages literally use them everywhere (interfaces and so on): yes, there's a cost, but it won't affect visibly your code unless you're in a long running loop with an high frequency required.
- Both of them? Profile! You need to measure and reason about the cost of that call and, if too expensive, you will look for a faster way to go for. But to profile you have to have a base to work with!